# ElementArrayFinder.filter() - how does it work under the hood?

Tags: javascript, protractor, typescript

In my UI, I have a project tree that contains a list of components that are in a project. Once my current spec is done running I'm calling a page object function to delete all the components to clean up the workspace before moving on to the next spec. I'd say about 50% of the time I'm noticing a stale element reference error on the line with my `.filter()` function. I added some log statements to see if I could figure out what's happening and noticed some behavior I didn't understand. It seems like for every component in my list, the filter function is running four times. Anyone know if this is expected behavior?

This is my delete function:

```
public async deleteAllComponents(): Promise<void> {
    await this.componentsTab.click();

    // get list of all current components
    const components = element.all(this.projectComponentsLocator);
    const componentNames = await components.getText();

    // delete each component
    for (const name of componentNames) {
        await this.deleteComponentFromProjTree(name);
    }
}
```

This is the function that is throwing the stale element reference error:

```
public async deleteComponentFromProjTree(componentName: string): Promise<void> {
    await this.componentsTab.click();
    // get new list each time because list goes stale after a component is deleted
    const components = element.all(this.projectComponentsLocator);        

    log('components found:', await components.count());
    log('deleting component:', componentName);

    const relevantComponent = await components.filter((component: ElementFinder) => {
        return component.getText().then((text: string) => {
            log('current component:', text);
            log('relevant component found:', text.includes(componentName));
            return text.includes(componentName);
        });
    })
    .first();

    await relevantComponent.click();

    const componentMenu = relevantComponent.$(this.componentMenuLocator);
    await componentMenu.click();

    if (await this.deleteOption.isPresent()) {
        await this.deleteOption.click();
        await this.confirmDeleteBtn.click();
    } else {
        // component cannot be deleted so just exit menu
        browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ESCAPE).perform();
    }
};
```

When I turn on the debug logging here is what I see in the console. Why does it seem like each component is running through the filter function 4 times? When there were 2 components found the function ran 8 times, when there was only 1 it still ran 4 times. What's this all about?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't think that your usage of getting text is correct.We need to get the text individually from each element, something like this:

```
element.all(by.css('something')).map(function(elm) {
 return elm.getText();
 }).then(function(texts) { 
texts.forEach(...); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I've already found a workaround. The problem was that there was too many elements in the list and protractor was having issues looping over them all. I found a different way to make it work with a smaller list of elements.